# How to make python close a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-webbrowser

So, with python i've seen that you can open a website using the code

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http://www.example.com", new=2)
```

but i really want to know how you could close the same specific tab using python.
If you can help please do. Thank you.

Comment: Try this answer with selenium: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186844/how-to-close-an-internet-tab-with-cmd-python

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. You might wanna try Selenium though.

[How to open and close a website using default browser with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33953776/how-to-open-and-close-a-website-using-default-browser-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

`webbrowser` module has no methods to close browser's tabs